# Filtering Word Embeddings from word2vec

Tags: python, gensim

I have downloaded Google's pretrained word embeddings as a binary file here (GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz). I want to be able to filter the embedding based on some vocabulary.

I first tried loading the bin file as a KeyedVector object, and then creating a dictionary that uses its vocabulary along with another vocabulary as a filter. However, it takes a long time.

```
  # X is the vocabulary we are interested in 
  embeddings = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors- 
  negative300.bin.gz', binary=True) 

  embeddings_filtered = dict((k, embeddings[k]) for k in X if k in list(embeddings.wv.vocab.keys()))
```

It takes a very long time to run. I am not sure if this is the most efficient solution. Should I filter it out in the  `load_word2vec_format`  step first?

Answer (score 1):

Your `dict` won't have all the features of a `KeyedVectors` object, and it won't be stored as compactly. The KeyedVectors stores all vectors in a large contiguous native 2D array, with a dict indicating the row for each word's vector. Your second dict, with a separate vector for each word, will involve more overhead.  (And further, as the vectors you get back from `embeddings[k]` will be "views" into the full vector – so your subset may actually indirectly retain the larger array, even after you try to discard the `KeyedVectors`.)

Since it's likely that a reason you only want a subset of the original vectors is that the original set was too large, having a `dict` that takes as much or more memory probably isn't ideal.

You should consider two options:

- `load_word2vec_format()` includes an optional `limit` parameter that only loads the first N words from the supplied file. As such files are typically sorted from most-frequent to least-frequent words, and the less-frequent words are both far less useful and of lower vector quality, it is often practical to just use the first 1 million, or 500,000, or 100,000, etc entries for a large memory & speed savings.
- You could try filtering on load. You'd need to adapt the loading code to do this. Fortunately you can review the full source code for `load_word2vec_format()` (it's just a few dozen lines) inside your local gensim instalation, or online at the project source code hosting at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/9c5215afe3bc4edba7dde565b6f2db982bba5113/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py#L123

You'd write your own version of this routine that skips words not of interest. (It might have to do two passes over the file, one to count the words of interest, then a second to actually allocate the right-sized in-memory arrays and do the real reading.)